# switch for 1MHZ sine wave

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches, mosfet-driver

[image]I am  trying  to  build  a  switch  that can  cut  by  control  the sine wave V1
From  the  load  R1.
The  main  problem  is  that  we  have  a  parasitic  capacitor  between  the drain  and  source
So  in  high  frequency  this  parasitic  capacitor  is  act  as  bypass and  I  get  a  signal  also  when 
V2 = 0.

1. I can't use     a  really as  I  need  to  switch  I in  100HZ.
2. SSR  - solid-state relay  is  also  not  good  for  that from  the  seam parasitic  capacitor  .

Any  idea  will be  helpful

Thanks
Aharon.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffbdJO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg1m42.png)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider using two switches - one in series to the load resistor from the source and then another across the load resistor. When one switch is activated the other one is off and vice versa.

Comment: Or - assuming you're not allowed to short out the load ... 3 switches in a "T" network. Open the top two, and close the third to ground the  common node.

Comment: Hi    Andy

 Sorry  but  see  my  update.
Now   to  be  clear I need  to  switch  between  sine  wave   and   DC  voltage  on  the  seam load.
For  example    10ms   sine  wave     then  5ms  DC  voltage .

How  can  I  prevent the  high  frequency  parasitic  capacitor  ?

Comment: Put a 1uF capacitor in series with the shunting switch or modify it like Brian says so there are two series switches and a shunt switch in the middle. Anyway, if the DC "switch" has say 10 ohm on resistance and the other switch has 10pF capacitance the attenuation is still going to be significant circa 64 dB. How much AC attenuation do you need?

Comment: @user96653 You said "So in high frequency this parasitic capacitor is act as bypass and I get a signal also when V2 = 0" - how can that be possible because V2 is THE sinewave signal and if V2 is zero you CANNOT get a signal.

Comment: hmm..........Andi  please   see  that  V2   is  the  sine  wave  generator   while V1  is  controling  the  switch.

Comment: as  well   as  i  hope  that  i  understand the "T" like Brian says  and  i am  trying  to  run  LT-SPICE simulation

Comment: btw…  I  am  new  here .  how  can  I  load  a sketch  along  the  answers?

Comment: Hijack an answer to load the sketch and someone will embed it into your question. Make sure you state you are hijacking an answer for this purpose or you might get a down vote. Once the picture appears in your question you can delete the fake answer.

Comment: HI  Andy  and   Brian...............   see  the  update …….it  work  just  fine   many  thanks.